# ckeditor return from dialog string

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Please tell me how to make the line return when pressed to display (html) it.
dialog js file

```
 onOk: function() {
            var dialog = this;

            var collection_group_n = dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'migx_collection_group_n');
            var vk_post_id = dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'vk_post_id');

            var align = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'align');
            var xs = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'xs');
            var sm = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'sm');
            var md = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'md');
            var lg = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'lg');

            var result = '[!$ImgGroup? &group_id="' + migx_collection_group_n + '"]';
        }
```

plugin.js

```
editor.addCommand('insertImgCollection', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('imgGroupDialog', {

        } ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to reset the cache.
    onOk: function() {
                var dialog = this;

```
            var collection_group_n = dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic' , 'collection_group_n');
            var vk_post_id = dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'vk_post_id');

            if (collection_group_n == '' && vk_post_id == '') {
                alert("Не заполнены главные параметры!");
                return;
            } else if (collection_group_n != '' && vk_post_id != '') {
                alert("Только один из главных параметров должен быть!");
                return;
            }

            var align = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'align');
            var xs = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'xs');
            var sm = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'sm');
            var md = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'md');
            var lg = dialog.getValueOf('tab-adv', 'lg');

            var result = '[!$ImgGroup? ' + (collection_group_n != '' ? '&group_id="' + collection_group_n + '"' : '&post_id="' + vk_post_id + '"') + (align != '' ? ' &align="' + align + '"' : '') + (xs != '' ? ' &xs="' + xs + '"' : '') + (sm != '' ? ' &sm="' + sm + '"' : '') + (md != '' ? ' &md="' + md + '"' : '') + (lg != '' ? ' &lg="' + lg + '"' : '') + ']';

            this._.editor.insertText(result);
        }
```